# Comparing records of last created file with next file : Python Scraping BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, duplicates

I am scraping this [Platform](http://www.epa.ie/hydronet/#Water%20Levels) with Selenium and BS4, i am able to retrieve all the information i want. The issue is platform contains sensor readings and few sensors are not updated every day, so i want to compare records of last scraped file with next file to be created.

Example:

I created xyz.csv file today which contains 200 records and tomorrow i will execute my code to collect information but before creating new file i want to check duplication with last created file. Added the execution will run everyday so in my opinion checking last created file would be good, but i am open to suggestions.

I am using the following code for scraping the information:

```
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import uuid
import csv
import dateutil.parser as parser
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt
from time import gmtime, strftime, localtime
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

class crawlHydro():
   
    def __init__(self):
        print("hurray33")
        global downloadDir
        global uFileName
        global filname
        downloadDir = ""
        uFileName = str(uuid.uuid4())
        filname = downloadDir + uFileName + ".csv"
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
        # Set Firefox preferences for headless crawling
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                          "attachment/csv")
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Initialize webdriver and target URL
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, firefox_options=options)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("hurray")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.driver.get("http://www.epa.ie/hydronet/#Water%20Levels")
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def crawl(self):
        print("see")
        driver = self.driver
        # Finds elements available on the target page for interaction/action
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
        driver.find_element_by_id("dijit_MenuItem_3_text").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="All"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Active EPA/LA (239)"]').click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') #Extract page content using BS4
        headers = []
        valueArr = 'LastReadTime'
        for m in soup.find_all("th"):
            headers.append(m.get_text())
        headers.append(valueArr)
        #print(headers)
        new_data = [[c.text.rstrip(" km²") for c in i.find_all('td')]  for i in soup.find_all('table')[5::]] #Extract table content i.e. column and rows
        new_data = [[dt.strptime(i, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M').strftime('%d-%m-%YT%H:%M+00') if re.match("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}",i) else i for i in m] for m in new_data] # Convert time to ISO 8601
        timerecorded = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M+00", gmtime())
        value = timerecorded
        finalDataList = []
        """Loops removes unnecessary rows"""
        for row in range(len(new_data) - 4):
            finalDataList.append(new_data[row])
        print(finalDataList)

        with open(filname, 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(headers)
            writer.writerows(finalDataList)
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        # os.system('pkill firefox')
        # os.system('pkill plugin-container')
        # os.system('pkill geckodriver')clear
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = crawlHydro()
    obj.crawl()
```

Can any one help me follow right direction?

Comment: Why did not choose to use database, it is easy to find duplicate data and export as csv

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the idea is to preprocess data before ingesting to some database